# Error in Fine-tuning VILT ImageandTextClassification. Make sure to match the number of images in the model with the number of images in the input

Tags: python, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to **fine-tune the ViltForImagesAndTextClassification model** for my custom dataset by using the following code:

```
from transformers import ViltForImagesAndTextClassification
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

model = ViltForImagesAndTextClassification.from_pretrained("dandelin/vilt-b32-finetuned-nlvr2",
                                                            label2id = {label: str(i) for i, label in enumerate(valid_labels)},
                                                            id2label = {str(i): label for i, label in enumerate(valid_labels)},
                                                            ignore_mismatched_sizes=True)

model.to(device)
```

While this is how the data is processed and being fed into the model:

```
batch = next(iter(train_dataloader))
for k,v in batch.items():
  print(k, v.shape)
```

It generates the following output:

```
input_ids torch.Size([4, 40])
attention_mask torch.Size([4, 40])
token_type_ids torch.Size([4, 40])
pixel_values torch.Size([4, 3, 384, 384])
pixel_mask torch.Size([4, 384, 384])
labels torch.Size([4])
```

I have tried using the training loop in the following ways:

```
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=5e-5)

model.train()
for epoch in range(50):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
   print(f"Epoch: {epoch}")
   for batch in train_dataloader:
        # get the inputs;
        pixel_values = batch["pixel_values"].to(device)
        input_ids = batch["input_ids"].to(device)
        label_ids = batch["labels"].to(device)

        # batch = {k:v.to(device) for k,v in batch.items()}

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = model(input_ids=input_ids, pixel_values=pixel_values.unsqueeze(0), labels=label_ids)
        # outputs = model(**batch)
        loss = outputs.loss
        print("Loss:", loss.item())
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

However it always returns error as:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/vilt/modeling_vilt.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, pixel_values, pixel_mask, head_mask, inputs_embeds, image_embeds, labels, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
   1353             num_images = image_embeds.shape[1] if image_embeds is not None else None
   1354         if num_images != self.config.num_images:
-> 1355             raise ValueError(
   1356                 "Make sure to match the number of images in the model with the number of images in the input."
   1357             )

ValueError: Make sure to match the number of images in the model with the number of images in the input.
```

Model.config contains the following:

```
  "layer_norm_eps": 1e-12,
  "max_image_length": -1,
  "max_position_embeddings": 40,
  "modality_type_vocab_size": 3,
  "model_type": "vilt",
  "num_attention_heads": 12,
  "num_channels": 3,
  "num_hidden_layers": 12,
  "num_images": 2,
  "patch_size": 32,
  "qkv_bias": true,
  "tie_word_embeddings": false,
  "torch_dtype": "float32",
  "transformers_version": "4.35.0",
  "type_vocab_size": 2,
  "vocab_size": 30522
```